# Product ordering through flipcart

Tags: web, e-commerce

I have an eCommerce website which is having so many products. My client is having problem to deliver the ordered products. So here I am looking for a solution that, Is it possible to integrate   product ordering with Bit giants (like flipcart, snapdeal), so that the product delivery can take place by them. If any solution pls share.

Answer (score 0):

Multi channel fulfillment by Amazon is one to look at. Keep in mind that any fulfillment center is also going to charge to warehouse (store) the products. http://services.amazon.com/fulfillment-by-amazon/multi-channel.htm